# alam clock in ionic cordova application

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, alarm

I am using https://github.com/uniclau/AlarmPlugin plugin to build an alarm clock application using ionic cordova framework .

```
     Var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic']);
    myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal) { 

    var alarmDate = new Date();
    navigator.plugins.alarm.set(alarmDate, 
    function(){
      // SUCCESS
    }, 
    function(){
      // ERROR
    });

    })
```

This is my controller and i am getting Error Message like 
      " TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined " at

```
   navigator.plugins.alarm.set(alarmDate,
```

this line , i dont know how to solve this , can anyone help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that you installed the cordova plugin? And where are you testing this? Cordova plugins only work within emulators, simulator or actual devices. If you are testing this in the browser it will not work.